# What libraries for interactive 3D model in Android AR app?

Tags: android, 3d, augmented-reality

I'm asked to do an app with a 3D object mapped on a tag on the camera preview. The user should be able to rotate the 3D object on swipes, and to click on different area of the 3D object.

I'm investigating the different way to do it.

So far the best option I've found seems to be https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sdk/unity, but I can't find whether it's possible to interact with the 3d model (rotate on swipe, define clickable areas).

Has anyone any experience with that?

I guess I can do it with some OpenGL, but I have no experience with it and it seems quite complex to start off with.

Is there any other library I should consider?

Answer (score 1):

I would use OpenGL and start by the training tutorials on http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html. Hope this helps! If you follow these tutorials you will be able to do what you want. ive tried unity and it is a really good engine too. and of course you can make an object clickable with unity! maybe using unity would be easier but the documentation on opengl is huge and is not that difficult to implement at least with first steps. hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The [Metaio SDK](https://dev.metaio.com/sdk/getting-started/) can do all of that but I am not sure if it automatically provides the area of the model tapped, but you could [ask here](http://helpdesk.metaio.com/).